# What was this "gravel gum candy" product from the early 1990s?

Tags: candy, history

This is such a massive long-shot, but it's been eating me up for decades now. I need to at least try.

In the early 1990s, my brother and I used to walk to this local little grocery store (long gone) to buy these small Tetra Pak-contained little "gravel chewing gum" candy products.

I do not remember anything about the name, the logo, or even the illustration of the package, besides a vague memory of bright green, blue and pink shapes. I do, however, vividly remember what the actual product inside looked like. It was chewing gum of some sort, shaped like gravel (little blue rocks) of slightly varying sizes.

It is extremely unlikely that it was made exclusively for/by/in Sweden; this is almost guaranteed to be some sort of bulk-imported product from "somewhere in Europe" or indeed "somewhere in the world". I'm somewhat confident that the text/title on the product was in English, or at least not Swedish. I probably would have remembered it if it had been in Swedish, and I have never heard anyone mention this product or seen it for sale in any other store, even back in the day. I would know it instantly if I saw a photo of it.

I have created a little illustration which represents 100% of everything I remember visually about the package and the product inside.

Can anyone please identify this product for me? I would be very surprised to learn that it's actually still sold, because all such nice things from my childhood seem to have just disappeared long ago, but even just knowing the name and perhaps being able to find a photo of it would stir up such nostalgic feelings that it would almost be enough.

And if it's actually still sold, somewhere, well, then I'm going to order a few at any cost, even if they have likely changed to a "new improved recipe" several times during these years...

[image]

Comment: I can't help identify the product, but I can confirm we had something similar in the US in the 90s. I used to get it at the neighborhood market near my house.

Comment: Can also confirm that America had gum nugget candy like this in the 90s. I mostly remember Bubble Jug and Bubble Rubble, but those didn't come in a green carton. Dubble Bubble had a yellow box but it was rainbow bits. Looks like Topps had a green carton, but it was green gum nuggets inside.... Bubble Crush, Bazooka, and Hubba Bubba were things too. I forgot what a huge gimmick bubble gum was when I was a kid.

Comment: At least I didn't dream it all up! Although those plastic "jugs" may have been only in the USA, with us getting little Tetra Paks... Or it was just a similar kind of product and not related to the same company/name.

Comment: Does this look familiar? http://www.collectingcandy.com/wordpress/?p=18170

Comment: @KateGregory Well, not the logo and the packaging, but the shape and (possibly) size of the "gravels", yes. But ours were all blue. And it's not clear from the photos how big they are.

Answer (score 6):

Oohh I remember this!

I loved the apple juice ones. My dad used to get them every time he went to the US.

A quick search with "candy" "gum" "apple" "milk carton" got me to this link:

[Topps Bubble Gum Juice Cartons!](https://dinosaurdracula.com/blog/topps-bubble-gum-juice-cartons/)

Hope it helps!